# Ctrl+Shift+C different behavior in regural Firefox and Firefox developer edition/aurora. Broken?

Tags: firefox, firefox-developer-tools, firefox-developer-edition

After pressing ctrl+shift+c in both cases the Inspector tab opens if it's closed. The difference is that in regular Firefox the "Pick an element from the page" is activated while in aurora Firefox it isn't. 
I thought that the given shortcut is for the "Pick an element from the page" and ctrl+shift+I is for Inspector tab. So first thoughts was that something is broken, tried searching for it - nothing (maybe wrong keywords or smth). Compared my settings on both of them - nothing. Then I came across few bugzilla reports one of which even asked for that feature. So now I'm lost.
Is ctrl+shift+C supposed to be a shortcut to "Pick an element from the page" or not? Based on [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Keyboard_shortcuts) no, but then why does it work like that on regular Firefox?
Which of the two behaviors is the right one?
Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue being tracked in [this bug](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1245654).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Don't know how i missed it when I was searching BugZilla. Status-firefox47: fixed hurray!